# How to use parent class variables from child class

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class parent{
int a;
}

class child extends parent{
//how to get access to "a" here?
}
```

Obviously declaring another variable of the same name `int a` will use it as it is from class `child`.

Comment: Just use it. It's accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keyword `super`. `super.a` should retrieve the parent's a variable even if it is defined again in child.

Comment: And is there a way to retrieve values in the parent from the child(s)?

Comment: @clytemnestra Nope, the parent doesn't know anything about the children since the children could have a very different implementation. You can use [abstract methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) as a way of guaranteeing a child will implement certain functions. So, if you wanted child to return it's own a value, you could have `public abstract int getA();` in the parent and the child will have to create that functionality, eg by returning it's own `a`. (Parent would need to be an abstract class though).

Comment: @LadyBernkastel if all he wants to do is retrieve the values, you should be able to accomplish that with the [getSuperClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass()) method and then using getDeclaredFields(). It's reflection, but the answer is actually YES.

Comment: @rpg711 Ah right, I'm not familiar with reflection so I did not know that. Learn something new every day :)